# Generating wordpress menu from custom taxonomies

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy, custom-post-type

I've created a custom post type (products) that has some custom taxonomies.  One of which is 'category'.  I would like to have my menu under Products generated automatically with the custom taxonomy 'category' so that on the menu they can click `PRODUCTS -> <category>` and it will take them to a list of that particular products with that category (I've already got a page that displays a single product, and a page that lists ALL the products).  Note that some `category` taxonomies will have children and I would like to show that in the menu too.

I'm somewhat new to wordpress and the only way I know how to create the menu is through the wp-admin, but I don't want to go in and create a page/menu for each category and subcategory.

Is what I'm talking about even possible?  Thank you!

Custom Post Type is here:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_product_post_type' );

function create_product_post_type() 
{
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Products', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Product', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'product'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Product'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Product'),
        'new_item' => __('New Product'),
        'view_item' => __('View Product'),
        'search_item' => __('Search Products'),
        'not_found' => __('No products found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No products found in Trash'),
        'parent_item_colon' => '',
        'menu_name' => 'Products'           
        );

    $args = array(
        'label' => __('Products'),
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        '_builtin' => false,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'menu_icon' => get_bloginfo('template_url').'/functions/images/product.png',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => array( "slug" => "product" ),
        'supports' => array('title'), //MAYBE add thumbnail later!
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true

        );

        register_post_type( 'product', $args);  
}
```

And here is the taxonomy:

```
function create_productcategory_taxonomy() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name' =>_x( 'Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Categories' ),
        'popular_items' => __( 'Popular Categories' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Categories' ),
        'parent_item' => null,
        'parent_item_colon' => null,
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Product Category' ),
        'update_item' => __( 'Update Product Category' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Product Category' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New Product Category' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate categories with commas' ),
        'add_or_remove_items' => __( 'Add or remove product categories' ),
        'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Choose from the most used categories' )
        );

    register_taxonomy('productcategory', 'product', array (
        'label' => __('Product Category'),
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'product-category'),
        )); 
}
```

Comment: Not clear.What is post type, what are the taxonomies, etc.

Comment: Sorry the custom post type is called Product.  the Taxonomy is Category.  I'll update my post to show you each in code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [wp_list_categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories). It exports the categories from a taxonomy with links to the depth of your choosing. (so as many children categories as you want) formatted as a list (e.g. with `<ul>`and `<li>` elements). 
I would add this where the menu you want to replace would go in your template. Hope that helps, but I'll come back and be more specific if it doesn't. 
I forgot to mention that the pages that it links to go to category pages. See [here.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)

Comment: Ahh thank you!  Playing around around I was able to successfully list all my categories and subcategories.  I have made my menu in the wp-admin, but it looks like I can play around with it using wp-nav-menu function.  Can I edit the menu I already have programatically or do I need to create a new menu from scratch?

Comment: You can use a filter to edit the output of wp_nav_menu, but for some more info, I would have a look [here.](http://www.kriesi.at/archives/improve-your-wordpress-navigation-menu-output).

Comment: Ouch thats a bit overwhelming.  I might just use the get_categories instead.  Thanks.